# Parse a list of names from 'First Last' to 'First.Last'

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a text based list of names and convert it to a format for active directory.

My goal is to have a string like this:

```
"Bob Smith, John Long, Matt Ball"
```

into

```
"Bob.Smith; John.Long; Matt.Ball"
```

So far I've done:

```
names = 'Bob Smith, John Long, Matt Ball'
x = names.replace(',', ';')
print(x.replace(' ', ''))
```

With the result:

```
"BobSmith;JohnLong;MattBall"
```

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Replace comma+space with semicolon, then replace space with period, then replace semicolon with semicolon+space.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

#### Change

You have to make just a small adjustment on what is been replaced:

```py
string = 'Bob Smith, John Long, Matt Ball'
string = string.replace(' ', '.').replace(',.', '; ')
print(string)
```

#### Result

```py
'Bob.Smith; John.Long; Matt.Ball'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
'; '.join(['.'.join(n.strip().split(' ')) for n in names.split(',')])
```